# Problema cargando imagen

Tags: java, eclipse

Tengo una aplicación , que cuando la ejecutó desde el IDE, me carga de pantalla principal una imagen con una barra de progreso. El problema está que cuando exportó el archivo a un ejecutable , la imagen desaparece pero la barra de progreso sigue apareciendo. Y no entiendo por qué con él IDE si que funciona , pero con el .Jar no.

Esta es la clase main:

```
  import sun.applet.Main;


  import java.awt.Color;


  import javax.swing.ImageIcon;


  public class PantallaCargandoMain {


    cargando screen;

    public PantallaCargandoMain() {
        inicioPantalla();
        screen.velocidadDeCarga();
    }

    private void inicioPantalla() {

        ImageIcon myImage = new ImageIcon("src/dado/LogoInicio.png");
        screen = new cargando(myImage);
        screen.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        screen.setProgresoMax(100);
        screen.setVisible(true);
        screen.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                System.out.println(info.getName());
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        Inicio inicio = new Inicio();

        new PantallaCargandoMain();

        inicio.setVisible(true);
        inicio.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    }
}
```

Y esta donde "cargo" todo:

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;

       @SuppressWarnings("serial")

    public class cargando extends JWindow {

    BorderLayout borderLayout1 = new BorderLayout();

    JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel();

    JPanel southPanel = new JPanel();

    FlowLayout southPanelFlowLayout = new FlowLayout();

    JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();

    ImageIcon imageIcon;

    public cargando(ImageIcon imageIcon) {
        this.imageIcon = imageIcon;
        dibujaVentana();
    }

    public void dibujaVentana() {
        // setOpacity(0.1f);

        imageLabel.setIcon(imageIcon);
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(borderLayout1);
        southPanel.setLayout(southPanelFlowLayout);
        southPanel.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        this.getContentPane().add(imageLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.getContentPane().add(southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        southPanel.add(progressBar, null);
        this.pack();
    }

    public void setProgresoMax(int maxProgress) {
        progressBar.setMaximum(maxProgress);
    }

    public void setProgreso(int progress) {
        final int progreso = progress;
        progressBar.setValue(progreso);
    }

    public void setProgreso(String message, int progress) {
        final int progreso = progress;
        final String theMessage = message;
        setProgreso(progress);
        progressBar.setValue(progreso);
        setMessage(theMessage);
    }

    private void setMessage(String message) {
        if (message == null) {
            message = "";
            progressBar.setStringPainted(false);
        } else {
            progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
        }

        progressBar.setString(message);
    }

    public void velocidadDeCarga() {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
            for (long j = 0; j < 1000000; ++j) {
                String poop = " " + (j + i);
            }
            setProgreso("" + i, i);
        }

        dispose();
    }

}
```

Comment: Por fa, agreganos el código para poderte ayudar.

Comment: Asegúrate de que la imagen se encuentre dentro de tu jar y pueda ser accedida desde una ruta relativa y no absoluta.

Comment: Ya he añadido el código de las dos clases con las que pongo la imagen y la utilizo.

Answer (score 2):

Para poder leer un recurso desde un `jar`, no se puede tratar el recurso como `File`, pero hay que leerlo como `InputStream`.

Eso funciona en eclipse, pero no en un `jar`:

```
File image = new File(getClass().getResource("/image.png").toURI());
```

Eso es la manera de obtener recursos desde un jar:

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/image.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

En este caso que no aparece la imagen es porque en el .jar debes obtener la imagen de esta forma:

```
.getClass().getResource("/directorio imagen/imagen")
```

Por lo tanto este sería un ejemplo del cambio ( usando import javax.swing.ImageIcon;) :

```
//  ImageIcon myImage = new ImageIcon("/directorio/LogoInicio.png");   
ImageIcon myImage = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/directorio/LogoInicio.png"))
```